# Is there an sql script to get the date and time a query was run?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I wondered if anyone can help. I need to get the date and time an sql query was run. I would like the output to be in the following format; YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss  Does anyone know what sql to write get this information please?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag with the database platform.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It sounds like you want to know when a query _was_ run after the fact, e.g. when  did Mister Rogers check his cardigan count last week, not what the current date/time is to incorporate in a query. Perhaps you could clarify that point. You specifically _don't_ want a [date/time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeDataTypes) data type as the result, just a string in the specified format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the current timestamp in the query.  The standard SQL for that is:

```
select . . ., current_timestamp
from . . .
```

Most databases support this.  However, there are also bespoke methods such as `getdate()`, `now()` and `sysdate`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Answered my question